# c++ auto with multiple choices

Tags: c++, c++11

During my adventures with project I realised that I can't use the advantage of the new c++11 auto keyword if I want to initialise the parameter depending on the condition.

Basically I had a code snippet like this:

```
auto foo = bar::getfoo();
```

Which needed to be change to:

```
FOO foo
if(cond){
   foo = bar::getfoo();
} else {
  foo = baz::getotherfoo();
}
```

But then I need to declare the foo with the type (as the compiler can't know that I will be using the same type return. I was wondering if there is any way of using the auto keyword in such case.
The other solution which I came up with is using the ? : operator with such code:

```
auto foo = cond ? bar::getfoo() : baz::getotherfoo();
```

But if there is more then two functions to choose from I don't really want to chain the ? : operators. I am wondering if there is any good pattern to use in such case.

Comment: It's a shame you're restricted to C++11. In C++14, use a function or lambda with a deduced return type.

Comment: @mike almost every C++11 compiler supported enhanced return type deduction on lambdas pretty much out the gate.

Comment: The question is worded a little wrong. There are no multiple choices.  The choice is one, because all "paths" evaluate to the same type. However OP wants kind of "postpone" it after the variable declaration statement. For multiple choices `boost::any` or something like that woudl be needed.

Comment: @cerk Do you understand that the `if` clauses do assignment, while the first simple clause (and the `?` clause) does construction?

Comment: @Yakk: That may be true (I'm not familiar with every C++11 compiler, so can't comment), but the question is tagged "c++11", not "almost-every-c++11-compiler".

Comment: @Yakk I wasn't until the moment I tried to compile it with the const return type of bar::getfoo(). Which makes things go badly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your instincts to use the ? : operator are correct - it's a good idea to initialise a variable only once and avoid the redundant default construction/assignment cycle.

A way to do this is to defer the selection of the Foo creation to a small utility function:

```
auto make_foo() -> decltype(bar::getfoo()) 
{
    if (condition1()) {
        return bar::getfoo();
    }
    else if(condition2()) {
        return baz::getfoo();
    }
    else {
        return banana::getfoo();
    }
}

void foo_test() {

    auto foo = make_foo();
}
```

Note that because of Return Value Optimisation, this is extremely efficient.

If you have c++14 it's even nicer - the make_foo() function can deduce its own return type:

```
auto make_foo() {
    if (condition1()) {
        return bar::getfoo();
    }
    else if(condition2()) {
        return baz::getfoo();
    }
    else {
        return banana::getfoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is all fine but you need to define the type of the return of make_foo, so it is defeating the point of doing all the job because you can name the type anyway. The whole idea is decoupling the return type of bar::getfoo() and current file source ( so when you change it you don't need to change the other file source code, which is not the case here the c++14 case solves it but it is c++14 which I can't use)

Comment: @cerkiewny ok this can be done with a small edit, sec... done

Comment: Even one line: `return condition1() ? bar::getfoo() : condition2() ? baz::getfoo() : banana::getfoo();`

Answer (score 5):

This is what [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is for. It will provide you with the type of an expression, without actually evaluating (and you could implement auto in terms off):

```
decltype(bar::getfoo()) foo;
if (....) {foo = ...;} else {foo = ...;}
```

Comment: this approach will not work for const types due to the assignment modifying their content.

Comment: @cerkiewny That's an unrelated issue which would also apply in case the type is actually known in advance and in which case it would probably be time to either use a ternary or if there are many possibilities a lamda. You could use Yakks first example, but replace the if else construct.

Comment: @Lanting what I believe cerkiewny is referring to is that decltype() may resolve to, say "const int&" (if that's the return value) whereas auto would resolve to just "int", defining a mutable copy (which I would argue is the correct behavior in this case). You can solve this by using remove_const and remove_reference traits, but it quickly becomes cumbersome

Answer (score 4):

```
auto a = foo();
```

constructs `a` from `foo()`;

```
std::decay<decltype( foo() )>::type a;
if(cond){
  a = foo();
}else{
  a = bar();
}
```

default constructs `a` then assigns to it the result of `foo()` or `bar()` based on `cond`.

`decay` is needed as otherwise of `foo()` returns a reference or a const `decltype` will deduce the 'wrong' type for `a`.

```
auto a = [&]{
  if (cond)
    return foo();
  else
    return bar();
}();
```

uses a C++14 feature (that most C++11 compilers supported early on), but conditionally calls either `foo` or `bar` and constructs `a` from it.  This logicalky requires an extra move, but the compiler will almost certainly elide it so it won't actually happen.

Comment: Please clarify which c++14 feature your bottom example needs. I've not seen a compiler that supports lambdas and does *not* support that.

Comment: @lefticus it needs enhanced return type deduction for lambdas.  Under C++11, lambdas that consist of one statement can be return type deduced.  Under C++14, the lambda return type deduction that *every* C++11 compiler I have ever tried is required (including the above), which among other things allows multiple statements.  The C++14 style was (from what I can recall) always intended, but the C++11 "easier" one was put in (to make it easy for compiler implementers maybe).  Apparently the C++14 style was easy enough.